# How to check if a variable is a DOMDocument object?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a function let's say `readChildElementsFromXml()` which takes $domDocumentObject as parameter.

> I want to check if the passed argument is a DOMDocument object or not.

Is there any `is_domDocument()` function or something like this in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried something till yet?

Comment: Hi Sahil, not really. But your solution is working for me. May I ask why have you deleted your answer? :)

Comment: done :)
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **No**. There is not a function like `is_domDocument()`, You can try something like this.

```
function is_domDocument($object)
{
    if($object instanceof DOMDocument) {
        echo "Its an object DOMDocument";
    }
    else {
        echo "Not DOMDocument";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMDocument
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php

```
<?php 

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('book.xml');
if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
}

?>
```